# When I send through MobilePush to my iOS app and it's in the foreground, why don't I get the push?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

I'm developing an app that uses ExactTarget MobilePush, but when I have the app running in the foreground and test push, I don't see anything on the screen. Is my push coming through? It seems to work ok when the app is in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the iOS behavior is is to not show an alert if the app is running when a push comes in. MobilePush respects this default behavior, and will process the push but not display an alert. If you'd like to change this, you may do one of the two following things.

1. In the SDK, call the following method to tell the SDK to show an alert: 

   `[[ETPush pushManager] shouldDisplayAlertViewIfPushReceived:YES];`
2. Implement your own UIAlertView in your app delegate's `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method.

Comment: Hi there, is there a MarketingCloudSDK equivalent of the same?